# querying online database of free server via android app

Tags: android, sql, database

I am creating an app which queries an online database. I am using a mySql db hosted on a free web server. Can I create web services on free servers? Also can I query a database from my app directly without using web services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as RED_ has stated, you need Http POST to query your database. For the answer for free web server is Yes you can.

You can create some PHP file to execute and query specific functions Such as select and display list on your android App.

As far as i know, You are NOT able to query database directly and you need gateway to do this.  what i mean gateway is some files that bridging your app and the server's db. This gateway can send and receive JSON or XML objects then your android app can consume it.

Some good tutorial to begin with:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php

or call webservice in android

http://androidexample.com/WEBSERVICE/index.php?view=examplecloud&scat=26

if you need more detailed description, just create another question thread.

hope this helps.

Comment: can u also suggest a way of doing that and a few sites that provide free server space and support for web services

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you need a .php file on the server that you will Http post to. That will talk to the MySQL database and return the information. This may not be 100% accurate but I tried it on a small local server and it worked. You cannot directly talk to a MYSQL database from my understanding.

What else have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

No you cant query the database from android with out some webservice or some sort of application that will be in the middle between the android application and the database .

and you can create a web service in your free host

Hope that Helps